# Java Cucumber - step definition implements En interface - possible in java 11?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

Java Cucumber - step definition implements En interface - how to use it ?

The following code does not work. Could you repair it ?

`Method Given("^Customer is on landing page$", () throws error "method call expected"`

I am using Java 11.

```
import static utils.BasePage.driver;
import io.cucumber.java.af.En;

public class LandingPageStepDefs implements En {
    
    @Override
    public String value() {
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
        return null;
    }
    
    LandingPage landingPage = new LandingPage(driver);

    public LandingPageStepDefs() {
    
        Given("^Customer is on landing page$", () -> {
            landingPage.verifyTextOnBanner();
        });   
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably meant to import `io.cucumber.java8.En`. Make sure you also have `cucumber-java8` as a dependency.

Comment: You should also review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask because this question is impossible to answer by most without any more context.

Comment: in Java 11 you cannot import io.cucumber.java8.En.

Comment: that is a strange thing to say. Why?

Comment: so try - becaue I see error when in Java 11 I want to import  io.cucumber.java8.En.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had to import dependency, and now works

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
    <version>7.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```